# Deleting product from added bags isn't working in Redux-Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using Redux-Toolkit and trying to delete a product from my cart (Bag) but it's not working when I'm trying to use

```js
removeBook(state, action) {
  state.books = state.books.filter(book => book.title !== action.payload)
}
```

whereas it works in this way

```js
removeBook(state, action) {
  state.books.splice(action.payload, 1)
}
```

What is any explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method works then it would seem you are dispatching the `removeBook` and passing an index as the payload value.

```js
removeBook(state, action) {
  state.books.splice(action.payload, 1);
}
```

```
{books.map((book, index) => (
  <div key={book.title}>
    <h2>{book.title}</h2>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => dispatch(removeBook(index))} // <-- passing index
    >
      X
    </button>
  </div>
)}
```

If you want to use the index and filter:

```js
removeBook(state, action) {
  state.books = state.books.filter((book, index) => index !== action.payload);
}
```

```
{books.map((book, index) => (
  <div key={book.title}>
    <h2>{book.title}</h2>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => dispatch(removeBook(index))} // <-- passing index
    >
      X
    </button>
  </div>
)}
```

If you would like to use the book title to remove a book from state then pass the book's title value.

```js
removeBook(state, action) {
  state.books = state.books.filter(book => book.title !== action.payload);
}
```

```
{books.map((book) => (
  <div key={book.title}>
    <h2>{book.title}</h2>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => dispatch(removeBook(book.title))} // <-- passing title
    >
      X
    </button>
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello I'm just making a guess as there is not enough code to pinpoint exactly the issue. The splice function modifies the state.books array, so that might be why it is working.

For the array filtering function, you would need to assign the results to `state.books`.

Comment: In the OP's code, they ***are*** assigning the filtering results to `state.books`.

Comment: I was referencing the original posts, but I see OP has updated the question and that this has been solved. Thanks for helping!